# Verilog Iteration error

Tags: verilog, vivado

Hi I am trying to execute this piece of code in Vivado 2017.2.1 and I keep getting this error

[Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations

```
while (side == 1)
  begin
  ball_x<=ball_x - 11'd10;
  end
while (side == 0)
  begin
  ball_x<=ball_x + 11'd10;
  end

if (ball_x <14)
begin
side=0;
end
else if (ball_x>1394)
begin
side=1;
end
```

this code is to get a ball to change directions when it has hit the 10px wide border. I googled it online and apparently Vivado did not support a while loop a few versions back but has added support recently and so this should work?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057265/how-to-synthesize-while-loop-in-verilog

Comment: Take the example of your first while loop. This continuously subtracts 10 from `ball_x` while `side` is 1. But you never change the value of `side` within the loop, so this loop will loop forever. This is an infinite loop in simulation and, because of that, synthesis cannot possibly design hardware to behave like this. I think you have some very fundamental misunderstandings of what it is your are doing and suggest you start with some much simpler designs. Have a look at the introduction to Verilog on [my company's website](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog_designers_guide/), for example.

Comment: ah you a very right about the misunderstandings, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seem to be written to be synthesizable at all, and you need to understand how the FPGA is intended to work.

Your first step should be to introduce a clock in your design, and understand how hardware is somewhat different from software.

Comment: apologies this is only an extract of the bit of the code that was causing the erro, I have a clock and etc...